# Any advice on fingering for stacked eighth notes?

Tags: piano, fingering

Any advice on right hand fingering for measures 29 and 31 (The eighth note runs), from "Mia and Sebastian's Theme" (Justin Hurwitz) from *La La Land*?

[image: mm. 26 – 32 of "Mia and Sebastian's Theme"]

Comment: @Aaron Is that relevant for the fingering?

Comment: @PiedPiper It's relevant for future users who have the same question.

Comment: @Aaron This is standard piano writing and the probabilty that a future user will be looking for fingerings for *these* measures of *this* piece is very small.

Comment: @PiedPiper In that case, this is a duplicate of every other question asking about how to finger specific passages that happen to be in thirds.

Comment: @Aaron Sounds like 'Mia and Sebastian's Theme' from 'La La Land' by Justin Hurwitz.

Comment: @Ergwun Bingo! Thanks! I knew it sounded familiar!

Comment: @Aaron There are numerous questions here on fingering thirds, all of them more or less duplicates. Almost none of them would be asked by someone who has ever practised scales in thirds.

Comment: @PiedPiper It seems like the two of you are in agreement, then, and that concords with my understanding as well. So why not choose or establish a proper canonical duplicate about how to figure out fingering for a run of thirds, and close the dupes?

Answer (score 5):

How about:

[image]

Here’s how this looks in action:

In general fingering is a personal and individual thing, so you need something that works for you.

Comment: the 2 & 4 on the second note have been switched

Comment: @GregMartin Thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is (for measures 4 to 7):

```
543454  3   545343  4
321232  1   312121  321
```

Answer (score 2):

As with the other answers, and as you probably already knew or intuited, the basic patter for descending thirds is 53, 42, 31. Then the question is about the next bit. Often, hitting it with 53 works well, and we're good for a few more thirds. In the first issue you mention, the next issue is choice of fingering to get into the next measure. I'd say this depends on you, and on the sound you want. You can have a little non-legato in the thirds, or a bit of it getting to that measure.

The second case is a little less regular, but, still, follows similar ideas. And the minor second in the ending measure could be 21 or 32 or... depending on your hands. :)